# Focus to next textbox in present devepxress gridview Error

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using a Devexpress 9 gridview which is bound to a datasource.

I have 3 columns shown below and say 10 row are generated after databinding.

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="New Rate" FieldName="Rate2"  VisibleIndex="1">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="t_newrate" ClientInstanceName="txt1" runat="server" Width="50px">
            <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s, e) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13)
            {
               txt2.Focus();
            }}" />
        </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="New Firm Rate" FieldName="Firm_Rate2" VisibleIndex="2">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="t_newfirmrate" runat="server" Width="50px" ClientInstanceName="txt2">
        </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Item_Id" FieldName="Item_Id"  VisibleIndex="3">
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

When I press enter in the first textbox it focus to the next textbox but to the textbox present in the **last row**. Why isn't it focusing the text box in the **same row**?

Any other way to approach this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happened by the fact that all ASPxTextBoxes in all DataRows have the same ClientInstanceName – “txt2”.

It is necessary to guarantee the unique ClientInstanceName for each ASPxTextBox inside “Firm_Rate2” column’s DataItemTemplate.

Review the [E2284](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2284.aspx) Code Central example to learn more on how to implement pair of dependent controls inside DataItemTemplates.

Comment: Thanks. was able to declare unqiue clientinstance name.